# ASP.net connection to an MS Access database

Tags: java, asp.net, ms-access, jdbc

I have a little question, I am taking my first steps in asp.net web api and am wondering whether a connection to an MS-Access database can be established via the controller and the URL and, if it is possible, how must the controller look?

ASP.net

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccessController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(nameof(GetDB))]
    public PhysicalFileResult GetDB()
    {
        string path = "path to ms-access";             
        return new PhysicalFileResult(path, "application/msaccess"); 
    }
}
```

Java Client

```
public void connect(){      
    String url = "localhost:5001/api/access/getdb"

    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + url, "", "");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java if you're looking for a ASP.net solution? How is the Java code relevant to your question?

Comment: Java is my client and I need the data from the ms-access DB and I would like to establish a connection in the post

Comment: That is not possible. You cannot access the Access database like that.

Comment: A shame, but thanks for your answer